# Why is this not working? New to Java. (Bukkit)

Tags: java, bukkit

Making an alert system in Java for a 1.8 Bukkit test server.
Extremely new to java.

```
            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage("§cUsage: /alert <message>");
                return true; // << "return true" means that it will stop running the code
            }

            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(args[0])) {
                String message = args[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                    message += args[i] + " ";
                }
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message + " "));
```

I don't know what's wrong with this. 
Whenever I do /alert in game it sends the first word fine but then no space then it goes straight to the next word. Then the rest of the message is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You currently initialize `message` with a value, but in your loop you don't prepend the space. Change

```
message += args[i] + " ";
```

to

```
message += " " + args[i];
```

Also, `args[0]` will **always** equals `args[0]` (and in the original case, so ignoring case for comparing it to itself is odd). Finally, and alternatively, if using Java 8+ you can use a collector like

```
String message = Arrays.stream(args).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message));
```

Comment: it just says "the value of the variable local message is not used"

Comment: Did you remove `Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message));`? If so, why?